# Login and get Webpage using API HtmlUnit in Java

Tags: java, html, asp.net, authentication, htmlunit

I'm trying to get a webpage. I'm getting the form, the textinput, the checkbox and the submit button so I can fill these ones trough java code.

First of all I'm getting these warnings (I presume that ScriptEngine fail to load some scripts):

```
oct 18, 2015 9:45:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
oct 18, 2015 9:45:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
oct 18, 2015 9:45:01 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
```

Anyway, after I've filled correctly in java the input and called the method click() on the submit button, I don't get the page that should be loaded after the submit. So, what am I missing?

Here's the html code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="Login.aspx?test=1" onsubmit="javascript:return doSomething_OnSubmit();" id="form">
//then there are some hidden inputs
//...
<input name="tax_code" type="text" maxlength="10" id="tax_code" style="color:Red;width:120px;" />
<input id="privacy" type="checkbox" name="privacy" onclick="activeConfirmButton()" />
//initially the confirm button is deactivated, after the checkbox is checked the confirm button is active with the onclick event added on it.
<input type="submit" name="Confirm" value="Confirm" onclick="javascript:Form_DoPostBack(new Form_DoPostBack())" id="Confirm" style="color:Blue;font-family:calibri;width:150px;Z-INDEX: 0" />
```

And here's the java code:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) 
        {
            /* turn off htmlunit warnings */
            //java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

            //webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
            //webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000);

            // Get the first page
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://example.com/examples/Login.aspx?test=1");

            final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form");

            final HtmlTextInput taxCodeTextField = form.getInputByName("tax_code");
            final HtmlCheckBoxInput checkboxInput = form.getInputByName("privacy");
            final HtmlSubmitInput confirmButton = form.getInputByName("Confirm");

            //Setting textfield and checkbox
            taxCodeTextField.setValueAttribute("TAX_CODE");
            checkboxInput.setChecked(true);
            //onclick of the checkbox, to activate the confirm button
            checkboxInput.click();

            // onclick of the confirm button
            final HtmlPage page2 = confirmButton.click();

            WebResponse response = page2.getWebResponse();
            String content = response.getContentAsString();
            System.out.println("HTML SOURCE: "+content);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
```

Comment: You should use `page2.asXml()`, since `.getContentAsString()` doesn't process the JavaScript. Otherwise, post your case with URL.

Comment: Please provide the tax code to use, and update your code with the correct input text name.

Comment: @AhmedAshour since that we're talking about personal info is that okay if I contact you in private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points to be considered.

- The website redirects to the same page once you click on the checkbox, so one must disable HtmlUnit caching.
- Clicking the checkbox should be done only once, and not `.setChecked(true)` and `.click()`
- Since clicking happens on the background, shown by the JavaScript `setTimeout()` in the checkbox `onclick` handler, one has to get a fresh page.

Below code updates the page and returns the result:

```
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

        // disable caching
        webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);

        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(url);

        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName(formName);

        final HtmlTextInput taxCodeTextField = form.getInputByName(taxCodeTextFieldName);
        HtmlCheckBoxInput checkboxInput = form.getInputByName(checkboxInputName);

        taxCodeTextField.type(taxCode);
        checkboxInput.click();

        //wait a little
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //get the main page
        HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) webClient.getTopLevelWindows().get(0).getEnclosedPage();

        HtmlSubmitInput confirmButton = page2.getFormByName(formName).getInputByName(confirmButtonName);

        final HtmlPage page3 = confirmButton.click();

        System.out.println(page3.asText());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So this string : "webClient.getTopLevelWindows().get(0).getEnclosedPage();" is what return me the fresh page after the JavaScript function called by the onclick event of the checkbox.